# Cómo poner archivos txt ya existente en una listbox en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una carpeta en red que tiene archivos txt quiero extraerlos para visualizarlos en una listbox en tkinter y después mandarlo otra carpeta en red y verificar con un condicional if si el txt está en la misma renombrar el que está con un caracter especial y mandar el que mande

Desde ya muchas gracias

PD: si hay alguna duda tengo un batch hecho en código podría mostrar el batch para una guia

```
-------------------------------------------------
:Transferir
cls
color 1a
echo Transferencia de Notas en Puestos
echo.
set/p cts="Ingrese Puesto Origen): "
set/p cts2="Ingrese Puesto a Copiar: "
set/p usr="Ingrese Usuario: "
pause
echo Verificando Usuario y Puestos
if exist \\XX.XX.XX.%cts2%\c$\xxx\%usr%.rtf (
echo.
echo El usuario del Puesto a Transferir se guardara con una copia con la tipografia de Usuario_.rtf
rename \\XX.XX.XX.%cts2%\c$\xxx\%usr%.rtf %usr%_.rtf
pause
echo Comienza la Transferencia del Puesto %cts% al Puesto %cts2%, por favor espere
pause
xcopy \\XX.XX.XX.%cts%\c$\xxx\%usr%.rtf \\XX.XX.XX.%cts2%\c$\xxx\%usr%.rtf
pause
echo La Transferencia de Notas del Usuario %usr% al Puesto %cts2% fueron EXITOSA !!
pause
) ELSE (
echo Usuario no Encontrado por Favor Verifique nuevamente el Puesto y Usuario
pause
)
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.